# Hadoop Development Tools for Eclipse not installing in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hadoop

I am getting the following error while installing hadoop development tools (HDT) for eclipse
[HDT Eclipse installation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0lXG.png)
How can I fix this error? Can anyone help me?

Thank you,

Comment: Sorry the error image i uploaded not shown on the thread. Kindly see the following error message I am getting. I am using Eclipse Mars under Ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS.

Comment: The error is: An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.hdt.core,0.0.2.incubating
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.apache.hdt.feature,0.0.2.incubating
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.hdt.hadoop.release,0.0.2.incubating
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.hdt.hadoop2.release,0.0.2.incubating

Comment: error continued: No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.hdt.ui,0.0.2.incubating

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the instructions highlight the wrong button.
You should click on:

Unzip the binary in a folder like:

```
C:/temp/hdt-0.0.2.incubating-bin
```

then:

```
Help --> Install new software --> add --> Local --> point to location "hdt-0.0.2.incubating-bin"
```

That should solve it ;-)